# Nodejs not working with Intellij Idea

Tags: eclipse, node.js, intellij-idea, grunt-contrib-watch

I would like to use Nodejs in sync with my IDE in order to do a browserify + gulp/grunt config for my frontend modules.I am currently on Eclipse which crashes when I attempt to install npm modules for my config.

I currently use grunt with my package.json and the gruntfile and the npm modules outside the project,I have also found that the watch task is useless because one has to refresh the files in Eclipse and then restart the server.

A friend recommended the Intellij Idea IDE.I have come to understand(painfully) that the Nodejs plugin is not available in the community edition and is not likely to be.I would like to know if there is any way to run tools such as gulp,npm,browserify with a seamless watch config in the IntelliJ IDEA.

I have a simple J2EE project that uses no frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more details in this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/nodejs.html).

Normally I recommend to use text advanced text editor like

1.[brackets](http://brackets.io/)

2.[atom](https://atom.io/)

3.[sublimetext](http://www.sublimetext.com/3)

Then it'l be more faster and easy.

Comment: I am concerned about how downloading and configuring nodejs as a library will affect my existing nodejs installation